# How to use Thread watcher

Tags: java, multithreading

Am working on a project where we are having issues with threads. There is an issue that makes the thread terminate and there is no way that the thread could restart automatically so we wanted to change this current implementation. 
we came up with an idea to Run a watcher thread to manage the file processing thread.
Can some one please suggest on how to make the thread that watches the state of the program and ideas on how to do this, please.

Edit: So basically this is what is happenning. A user uploads some media files which are written to a fileshare. a thread running in mobile services scans the media file and attaches to an email. In this process the thread terminates and it fails to attach the media to the email.

Below is the code from my servlet and the run method.

```
private synchronized void startProcessing() {
    boolean processor = false;
    try {
        Properties mProp = SystemUtil.filterProperties(SystemImpl.getInstance().getApplicationProperties("Media"));
        processor = (Boolean.parseBoolean(mProp.getProperty("processor", "false")) && Boolean.parseBoolean(System.getProperty("RunProcessor", "false")));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Unable to get 'processor' value from property file.  Defaulting to false.");
    }
    if (processor) {
        if (null != thread) {
            if (thread.getState().equals(State.TERMINATED)) {
                thread = new Thread(fProc);
            }
        } else {
            thread = new Thread(fProc);
        }
        if (thread.getState().equals(State.NEW)) {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "processor starting...");
            thread = new Thread(fProc);
            thread.start();
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "processor successfully started.");
        } else {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "processor thread is already running.");
        }
    } else {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "processor configured not to run.");
    }
}

public void run() {
    int sleepTime = 10000;
    try {
        sleepTime = Integer.parseInt(mProp.getProperty("ProcessorSleepTime"));
        waitTime = -(Integer.parseInt(mProp.getProperty("ProcessorWaitTime")));
        keepProcessed = Boolean.parseBoolean(mProp.getProperty("KeepProcessed"));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Unable to read property file.  Using default values.");
    }
    File filePath = new File(MResource.getMRepositoryPath());
    File processingPath = new File(filePath.getPath() + "/" + PROCESS_FOLDER_NAME);
    if (!processingPath.exists()) {
        processingPath.mkdirs();
    }
    File failurePath = new File(filePath.getPath() + "/" + FAILURE_FOLDER_NAME);
    if (!failurePath.exists()) {
        failurePath.mkdirs();
    }
    File processedPath = new File(filePath.getPath() + "/" + PROCESSED_FOLDER_NAME);
    if (!processedPath.exists()) {
        processedPath.mkdirs();
    }
    while (!stopProcessing) {
        isProcessing = true;
        logger.log(Level.FINEST, "Checking for files...");
        try {
            processFiles(filePath, processingPath, failurePath, processedPath);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "Thread sleep interrupted.");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error while processing files.", e);
        }
    }
    isProcessing = false;
    stopProcessing = false;
    logger.log(Level.WARNING, " file processor has stopped.");
}
```

Comment: `There is a process that makes the thread terminate` IMHO you should fix this root cause and not try to work-around. You're not going to make this any better with more threads.

Comment: please clarify `process` `program` and `thread` or rewrite your question to be more clear. Not sure how process (another process?) can stop (how?) a JVM thread

Comment: @user1445898: please see my edit above.

Comment: Just wrap the run() method of the thread in a try/catch. Or you can register an uncaughtException handler on the Thread or Thread group. Scanning for thread existence sounds awfully hacky, sounds like an anti-pattern to me. The proposed join() would be somewhat acceptable.

Comment: Sounds more like a externel process not like a Java thread you want to monitor here?

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be easier to fix the cause than to restart it.
There are only two ways to terminate a thread:

1. calling thread.stop(). This is deprecated and 99.9% not your case
2. exiting run() method via normal termination or exception. wrap your run method with try {... } catch (Throwable) finally{} and put some logging there and you will find out the reason.

If you really need a watcher, you can do something like that:

```
void run() {
    while (true) {
        thread.join();
        thread = new Thread(myRunnable);
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely not be terminating the thread. Maybe you should make the thread wait instead. To restart a thread you need to know it's exact state when it terminated. You'll have to save the state of that thread then reconstruct the correct thread perfectly. So you're first question is probably "How do I do that". Without knowing your program inside and out it's impossible to tell you. But that should be an absolute last resort. As it's an extremely terrible idea in almost every case.(Expect more bugs than you can handle)

TLDR;

That's a bad idea. Don't terminate the thread.

Edit: Well I guess you have to find the bug that's killing the thread first. If you don't find that then you won't be able to save the state of the thread before it dies anyways. You could try using print statements or a debugger

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I feel relaxed looking at the answer. And yeah we really don't want to terminate the thread, somehow its happening. And yes, I probably have the question "How do I do that" . Any api's, any frameworks. I was googling and found this java doc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html

Comment: thanks for all the valuable suggestions. I have edited my question with the code i have in place now, please suggest based on the code.

Comment: Does the try-catch not fix your problem? Do you know where the code breaks at?

Comment: the thread stops at the last line saying file processor has stopped

Comment: In your catch block can you add a print statement: print(e.getMessage()) so I can see the stack trace. Also can you post the code to processFiles()?

Comment: Hi, i was thinking to use executors framework as a thread watcher. Does this seems to be a good idea?

Comment: I have no experience using them, but have heard nothing but good things